# How to fetch parameters from ajax post request

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp-classic

The Javascript code is:

```
var str = "html=<p>Some htmlcode here<p><div>more htmlcode </div>";
saveProject(str);

function saveProject(str) {
if (str=="") {
    return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST","../demo.asp",true);
xmlhttp.send(str);
}
```

and the ASP file:

```
<%
response.expires=-1

x = Request.Form("html")

response.write x
%>
```

I need to fetch the str passed to xmlhttp.send() method and do some useful stuffs, but it looks like I'm missing something. The response is (an empty string). Any help is a appreciate!

Comment: Try to wrap the str into `encodeURIComponent` - `xmlhttp.send(encodeURIComponent(str));`.

Comment: Just the post is now the encoded str, but still the response is an empty string.

Comment: Isn't it `Response.Write(x)` the write syntax.

Comment: VBscript is case insensitive. response.write "some state" is completely right statement. Although I try with this statement Response.Write(x) . Still an empty string.

Comment: Also if i response.write "test" . The response is actually passed. So it's something with the Response.Form or the .send() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the request header solve the problem.

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```